# Do I need a transit visa at Bangkok?

Tags: visas, air-travel, indian-citizens, transit-visas, thailand

I have booked a Thai Airways flight from New Delhi to Taipei, with a layover in Bangkok.

My outbound ticket has two flights:

1) NEW DELHI to BANGKOK Suvarnabhumi (23:30 - 05:30)
2) BANGKOK Suvarnabhumi to TAIPEI (07:10 - 11:50)
Layover time: 01 hrs 45 minutes

My return ticket has also two flights:

1) TAIPEI to BANGKOK Suvarnabhumi (14:05 - 16:50)
2) BANGKOK Suvarnabhumi to NEW DELHI (17:55 - 20:55)
Layover time: 01 hrs 05 minutes

Can anyone tell me how to manage the timings, and do I need a transit visa in BKK?

Comment: What is your nationality? Indian? Did you book this as a single ticket?

Comment: Yes i am an Indian and it is a single ticket